# How to specify simulation class of Gatling in command line

Tags: maven, gatling

I have simple Gatling project and there two simulation classes (SimulationForAzure.scala & OtherSimulation.scala).
When I want chhose only one simulation and try to execute command

```
mvn -Dgatling.simulationClass=org.example.SimulationForAzure gatling:test
```

or

```
mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=org.example.SimulationForAzure
```

I get error:

```
Unknown lifecycle phase ".simulationClass=org.example.SimulationForAzure". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal
```

What is wrong?
And how to specify simulation class of Gatling in command line?

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <gatling.version>3.3.1</gatling.version>
    <gatling-maven-plugin.version>3.0.5</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-recorder</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here are my classes: [Simulations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpTp1.jpg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution myself.
I changed the pom.xml file. Now it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <gatling.version>3.3.1</gatling.version>
    <gatling-maven-plugin.version>3.0.5</gatling-maven-plugin.version>

    <className></className>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-recorder</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <simulationClass>${className}</simulationClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I execute in PowerShell

```
mvn gatling:test '-Dclassname=org.example.SimulationForAzure'
```

or

```
mvn gatling:test '-Dclassname=org.example.OtherSimulation'
```

everything works as expected.

Comment: Your -D variable should have a capital N: `'-DclassName=org.example.SimulationForAzure'`

Answer (score 8):

If simulation classes are under src/test/scala `gatling.simulationClass` property works fine:

```
src
   test
       scala
            com.myproject
                  simulation
                      Sim1.scala
                      Sim2.scala
                      ...
```

Plugin in pom.xml can be left as is:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
```

This command works:

`mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=com.myproject.simulation.Sim1`